# Add tag to lead in Intercom with Zapier

Tags: zapier, intercom

I was having issues tagging a lead in Intercom via Zapier. Zapier offers a "Tag User" action, but nothing for leads. Since Intercom requires leads to be tagged given their ID (and not by email), the existing Zapier action can not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
fetch('https://api.intercom.io/tags', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'YOUR TAG NAME',
    user: [{ id: input.leadId }]
  })
})
.then(function(res) {
  callback(null, JSON.parse(res.text()));
})
.catch(callback);
```